# Is it possible to specify which port my Netlify function is published on?

Tags: netlify, netlify-function

I would like my published production Netlify function to be accessed on a specific port e.g. https://Netlify-function-url:34567

Is there some way to specify the 34567 in this example?

Answer (score 0):

From Netlify support - it's not possible...